# How to prevent & becomes into &amp; when I add a tag value in an upload file using AWS.S3.ManagedUpload javascript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, put

I am developing a javascript function to upload files to S3 bucket in aws. I have to include a short description and for this I am using tags values inside S3 request like this:

```
      var upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
        partSize: 6 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 5,
        params: params,
        tags: [{Key: 'Key', Value: stateTag}, 
              {Key: 'desc', Value: convertToEncodeHTML(stateDescription)}]
      });
```

According aws documentations https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html  I have to convert special characters into html code.

To convert special characters into html code, I am using this javascript function:

```
    export function convertToEncodeHTML(string) { 
        var i = string.length, 
            a = []; 
    
        while (i--) { 
            var iC = string[i].charCodeAt(); 
            if ((iC < 65 || iC > 127 || (iC > 90 && iC < 97)) ) { 
                a[i] = '&#' + iC + ';'; 
            } else { 
                a[i] = string[i]; 
            } 
        } 
        return a.join(''); 
    }
```

This function works well but when I check the request in Chrome console I see that is rejected because of bad request 400.

The console shows that this request was sent:

```
<Tagging xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <TagSet>
        <Tag>
            <Key>Key</Key>
            <Value>myKeyValue</Value>
        </Tag>
        <Tag>
            <Key>desc</Key>
            <Value>retries en redis&amp;#44; agent backoff&amp;#44; new connector  </Value>
        </Tag>
    </TagSet>
</Tagging>
```

The "&" character was converted into "& amp;" which is rejected by aws:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidTag</Code>
    <Message>The TagValue you have provided is invalid</Message>
    <TagKey>desc</TagKey>
    <TagValue>retries en redis&amp;#44; agent backoff&amp;#44; new connector  </TagValue>
</Error>
```

Do yoy have any idea how to solve this problem?

I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you scroll down on the page you see that just putting `ÄMÄZÕÑ S3` is fine, without any additional encoding. Does your code work if you do not provide any special characters?

Comment: Yes, request works well without special charcters, the problem occurs when users add characters like comma